# 'disordered_select' method missing from Residue class

Tags: python, biopython

I cannot get this code working. It looks nearly identical to the instruction provided by biopython but just keep giving me the error

I am using  Python 3.7.6 and Biopython 1.81 with PyCharm community 2022.

```
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB.Polypeptide import PPBuilder


p = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)
structure = p.get_structure("1ak4", "AB-Bind-Database-master/1ak4.pdb")  # read PDB file 1AK4

model = structure[0]  # load default model
chain = model['D']  # load chain-D
residue = chain[488]  # find position 488 for mutation
residue.disordered_select("Gly")  # introducing mutation but this line keep throwing error
```

```
'Residue' object has no attribute 'disordered_select'
```

I have tried to reinstall biopython package and also different version of Python. I also tried to start with a completely fresh project. But there is little to try since the code I am using is literally a copy of Biopython's instruction code.

Comment: Have you looked at the types of ´`model`,`chain` and `residue`objects?

Comment: @СергейКох In fact yes, they all give the same error message somehow. If I want to call 'disordered_select'. I think user pippo is getting some insight about this error.

Comment: I mean chain, residue and atom is a subclass of entity and under a wrapper class which has this method. Judging from it I guess I am using the wrong method for introducing single point mutation. Could you show me the right way? Like for example if I have a mutation say like D:A488G for protein entry PDB 1AK4. Currelty I am doing it the basic way just load the chain as peptide string and replace the amino acid based on its residue position with the new character. Thank you.

Comment: see here https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/if-i-modify-a-pdb-file-with-a-specific-mutation-how-to-minimize-energy If I modify a PDB file with a specific mutation, how to minimize energy?

Comment: @pippo1980 thank you for the suggestion. I am no longer academic so academic license is not possible at this stage. Also the FoldX is a bit redundent. I am testing protein docking based on few data sets which one of the data using PDB ID + mutation annotation.  The folding was done separately by AlphaFold thus a simple sequence-based manipluation is sufficient to just get data right.

Answer (score 2):

thank you for the info. I am reading the manual further and find this.

1. Disordered_select was meant for residue object which already have the SPM info loaded which is not my case. Therefore the method does not exist as @BioGeek mentioned.
2. Apparently the way to actually introduce slicing or SPM is indeed by manipulation the peptide sequence via string-like strategy. Biopython tutorial mention it here
   http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec%3Amutable-seq
3. However in my case my residue position does not have to start at 0 or continious thus what I do is find the correspond position of amino acid by their relative residue position first. Therefore, the sequence index of each amino acid does not really match up with residue position in the PDB file.

So I made a bit my own solution. This may not be the prefect solution but kind of serving the purpose

```
from typing import List, Dict
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB.Polypeptide import PPBuilder
from Bio.PDB import Chain, Residue, Atom
import csv


class ResidueMutation:
    def __init__(self, mutation: str):
        """

        :param mutation: like "D:A488G"
        """
        str_len = len(mutation)
        self.chain_id = mutation[0]  # chain id
        self.org_res = mutation[2]  # original residue
        self.new_res = mutation[str_len - 1]  # new residue
        self.res_pos = mutation[3:str_len - 1]
        # print(self.__str__())

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.chain_id} {self.org_res} {self.new_res} {self.res_pos}"


def parser_mutation(mutations: List[str]):
    """
    return a map of mutation ResidueMutation
    :param mutations: like ["D:L483T","D:V486P","D:H487A","D:A488M","D:I491L","D:A492P","D:M496I"]
    :return:
    """
    mutation_map = dict()
    for mutation in mutations:  # processing mutation info
        res_mut = ResidueMutation(mutation)  # parse a mutation
        mutation_id = f"{res_mut.chain_id}_{res_mut.res_pos}"  # make a mutation id
        mutation_map[mutation_id] = res_mut  # put to map
    return mutation_map


def chain_seq_str(chain: Chain, mutation_map: Dict):
    chain_id = chain.id  # the designated peptide chain ID
    ppb = PPBuilder()  # to build sequence
    seq_list = list()  # prepare final sequence list for mutation operation
    for pp in ppb.build_peptides(chain):
        seq = str(pp.get_sequence())  # get sequence fragement
        seq_list += list(seq)  # appending sequence fragement together

    res_index = 0 # the residue index in seq_list, not real residue position
    if len(seq_list) > 0:  # should not happen but in case PDB ID wrong
        for residue in chain.get_residues():  # go through each residue
            residue_id = residue.get_full_id()  # not sure if useful
            resseq = residue_id[3][1]  # real residue position from PDB file
            mut_id = f"{chain_id}_{resseq}"  # unique ID of residue at peptide
            if mut_id in mutation_map:  # there is a mutation to be performed, peptide chain ID and residue position matched up
                mutation = mutation_map[mut_id]  # something converted from SPM annotation like this "D:A488G"
                seq_list[res_index] = mutation.new_res  # perform the SPM
            res_index += 1  # increase indexer

            # print(resseq, residue.get_resname())
        # end residue iteration
    # end of lenght check
    return "".join(seq_list)  # convert list back to string
```

Answer (score 1):

Your residue is not disordered

```
>>>residue.is_disordered()
0
```

Your `residue` is of type [`Bio.PDB.Residue.Residue`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/acf38909d8386d666a9c5b83e6a44f404470f09f/Bio/PDB/Residue.py#L21) but `disordered_select` is used in the methods [`disordered_add`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/acf38909d8386d666a9c5b83e6a44f404470f09f/Bio/PDB/Residue.py#LL127C9-L127C23) and [`disordered_remove`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/acf38909d8386d666a9c5b83e6a44f404470f09f/Bio/PDB/Residue.py#LL142C9-L142C26) of class [`DisorderedResidue`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/acf38909d8386d666a9c5b83e6a44f404470f09f/Bio/PDB/Residue.py#LL85-L85C24)

Comment: https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.PDB.Residue.html#Bio.PDB.Residue.DisorderedResidue : DisorderedResidue is a wrapper around two or more Residue objects.

It is used to represent point mutations (e.g. there is a Ser 60 and a Cys 60 residue, each with 50 % occupancy).

Comment: @pippo1980
Ok, thank you guys. Judging from the info, then I must be using the method for the wrong intention. I thought the method was meant to introduce mutation but apparently not.

Actually SPM is what I intend to do with this method. So could you show me how to introduce a single-point-mutation using biopython for a particular chain. Of course I am doing it now the stupid way by just convert an chain to string representation of peptide and replace the amino acid character manually based on residue position but I am sure there has to be a smarter way.